# Scanning an image and saving it in a specific folder

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have created a Windows Form application to scan any image.

After scan is complered it asks the user to save it in any folder, but I want the image to be saved in a specific folder.

The code I have used:

```
public class Scanner
{
    Device oDevice;
    Item oItem;
    CommonDialogClass dlg;

    public Scanner()
    {
        dlg = new CommonDialogClass();
        oDevice = dlg.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, true, false);
    }

    public void Scann()
    {
        try
        {
            dlg.ShowAcquisitionWizard(oDevice);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Scanner oScanner = new Scanner();
   oScanner.Scann();

   //Saving the image to the server directly
   button1.Text = "Image scanned";

   OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

   if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
   }            
}
```

Comment: Where does `Device` comes from ? Do I need some reference or someting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CommonDialog.ShowTransfer method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Example:

```
Device scanner = dialog.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, true, false);
Item scannnerItem = scanner.Items[1];
// TODO: Adjust scanner settings.

ImageFile scannedImage = (ImageFile)dialog.ShowTransfer(scannnerItem, WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatPNG, false);
scannedImage.SaveFile("path");
```

Comment: I used your code but in the path here it is necessary to provide the name of the image fil.for example  "D:\\scanned image\\lelo.jpg"  I just want to give the name of the folder which is scanned image here.i want lelo.jpg to be enterd by the user while saving....Can u plz share the complete code for me.

Comment: Do I need to add something in the references so that `Device` is known to the compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use scanning code in wpf C# using WIA. 
[Complete Scanning code in WPF C# using WIA, 
please visit this URL: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/08/scanning-images-in-wpf-via-wia](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/08/scanning-images-in-wpf-via-wia)